# SUM on COUNT table issues "invalid of group function"

Tags: mysql, count, sum

Query without SUM

```
select date_format(b.date,'%d-%b-%Y') as tanggal, b.nomor, b.no_polisi, a.ukuran, a.type , 
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Bottom', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Bottom',
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Middle', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Middle',
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Top', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Top',
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Bottom', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Bottom',
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Middle', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Middle',
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Top', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Top',
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Bottom', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Bottom',
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Middle', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Middle',|
if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Top', count(a.type), 0) as 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Top'|
from nota_pengiriman_detail a
inner join nota_pengiriman_master b on b.id = a.id_master
where b.proyek = 'kssk' group by b.no_polisi, a.type
```

and here image of the result
[link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8dbc.png)

but when I use SUM function there's alway return "invalid of group function"

Query with SUM

```
select date_format(b.date,'%d-%b-%Y') as tanggal, b.nomor, b.no_polisi, a.ukuran, a.type ,
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Bottom', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Bottom',
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Middle', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Middle',
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Top', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 40x40 10 M 4ea1/2" Top',
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Bottom', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Bottom',
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Middle', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Middle',
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Top', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 40x40 8 M 5ea1/2" Top',
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Bottom', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Bottom',
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Middle', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Middle',
SUM(if(concat(a.ukuran,' ',a.type) = 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Top', count(a.type), 0)) as 'SqPile 45x45 10 M 5ea1/2" Top'
from nota_pengiriman_detail a
inner join nota_pengiriman_master b on b.id = a.id_master
where b.proyek = 'kssk' group by b.no_polisi
```

and here image supposed to be like this [link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XTyM.png)

any ideas? where's parts I've missing?
Thank  you

Comment: There is a COUNT function within your SUM function, which throws error. Maybe you need to rewrite your query using subquery.

Comment: I use COUNT function for knowing how many column with condition above and grouping them by no_polisi but there's error comes

Comment: You can try break your statement into subquery. Or provide us with your table structure and some sample of data.